# PDOStatement::bindParam doesn't work after the first call

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a little problem writing a simple class that uses PDO to connect to the db.
The problem is that the PDOStatement::bindParam doesn't work after the first call in the cycle, I mean if I have two parameters to give to the PDOStatement the query doesn't return the rignt result, instead if i give only one parameter it gives the right result.

Here's the code:

```
public function query($sql, $params = NULL) {
        // Opens the PDO connection
        $this->open();

        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        if (isset($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                // This doesn't work after the second cicle.
                $this->stmt->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
            }
        }

        $result = NULL;
        if (!$this->stmt->execute()) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
        }

        // Closes the PDO connection
        $this->close();

        return $result;
}
```

And here's the PDOStatement::debugDumpParams:

```
SQL: [114]
SELECT 1
FROM   users
WHERE  EXISTS
       (
              SELECT *
              FROM   users
              WHERE  username = :username
              AND    password = :password) limit 1
PARAMS: 2
KEY:NAME: [9] :username paramno=0 NAME=[9] ":username" is_param=1 param_type=2
KEY:NAME: [9] :password paramno=1 NAME=[9] ":password" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you tried this with other tables?  As for using this to match a username and password, you really should be looking into using [`password_hash()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Comment: @NigelRen I'm using md5() function and a salt string to hash and then store the passwords, isn't that enough? And yes I've tried it with other tables

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I fixed it using PDOStatement::bindValue instead of bindParam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR always use `bindValue()` unless you want to use the special behaviour of `bindParam()`.

> ```
> foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
>     // This doesn't work after the second cicle.
>     $this->stmt->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
> }
> ```

The reason this doesn't work as intended is the misconception of what PDO means with `bindParam()`. It doesn't mean "bind the SQL parameter" but "bind the value (i.e. the parameter for *bindParam()*) as referenced variable". Thus when `execute()` is called, it will use the value for `$value` (which is the variable bound to all SQL parameters) at execution time, not at the time `bindParam()` was called.

Cf. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php where this behaviour is explained.

The solution is to use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`.